# UICollectionView and elastic cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm developing a multimedia publishing app and wanted to hear another opinion on this idea of mine.

I have a UICollectionView with cells of various types and sizes – text paragraphs, images, videos, ... I've modified the layout to arrange these cells into newspaper-like columns but since the cells almost never fit the view, there are often great gaps at the ends of the columns. I was thinking whether it would be possible to add a touch of elasticity to the layout. Many types of cells, like images and videos, can be squeezed or expanded a little without user ever noticing. Other cells, like text paragraphs, can be broken down into smaller pieces. The layout could use these modifications to even the columns in height.

Do you think it's technically possible to implement? Secondly, do you think this is a good approach for multimedia app with custom publishing format?

Thanks for your opinions,
Pete.

Comment: Just set the height of the CollectionViewCell according to it's contents?

Comment: Doing that causes the problem. Since `UICollectionViewCell` has different height, sum of heights almost never adds up to the height of the column. It's always lower and therefore, a gap occurs.

Comment: you change the height and the y of each cell. look at pinterest app for example. you'll get what I mean.

Comment: I see your point, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a custom uicollectionviewlayout you might be looking for. In this layout, you can design your own layout to organise cell's size and position.

Here is link :

https://github.com/johnny0614/YJZAlbumCollectionViewLayout

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think it's technically possible to implement?

Yes, it is.

> Secondly, do you think this is a good approach for multimedia app with custom publishing format?

Yes, sounds good.

I hope this helps you to write more specific questions.